# why the array reinitialized on every click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push some numbers to an array, and then I want to assign the array to a hidden input to posted with a form.

On each click I am pushing a value to the array, but the array seems to be reinitialized on each click, so it stores the last pushed value only.

**The full scenario:**

- open a popup modal contains a form (form loaded by ajax).
- select a category, then the category items will be loaded by ajax too. (the shared code below is in this page).
- click an item to get the full item details by ajax and load them in a div, and push the item ID to the array.
- the array that stored the chosen items IDs will be assigned to a hidden input element.

So if the user choose another category, the items page will be reloaded, and this is the reason why the array is reinitialized each time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var added_items = [];

            $('.items-list .one-item').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                if(added_items.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) < 0){
                    ajaxLoad('<?=Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('bookings/item'); ?>', $('.added-items'), {item:$(this).attr('href')}, true);
                    added_items.push($(this).attr('href'));
                    $('#added-items-list').val(JSON.stringify(added_items));
                }
                else{

                    alert("item already exist");
                }
            });
        });
```

So how I can save the items IDs and post them with the form.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or HTML ? Code looks good to me..

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(added_items, added_items.indexOf($(this).attr('href')));` at end of click function end?

Comment: That code should work, however, are you sure you are not reinitializing the `added_items` array in the `ajaxLoad` function?

Comment: @Piwwoli yes I am sure.

Comment: i guess this code is located in content which reloading by ajax

Comment: @Justinas it prints an array of one element each click.

Comment: Is `if(added_items.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) < 0)` condition returning `false` ? Can include `html` at Question ? Is page reloaded after `form` submit ?

Comment: `var added_items = [];` Try keeping this outside `document.ready` i.e. globally..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i tried, same result.

Comment: move it outside. otherwise this code is loaded every ajax call, at least move `var added_items = [];`

Comment: Is it possible to replicate this problem in `fiddle`?

Comment: guys, I have edited the question, your comments really helped me to re-figure the issue again. thanks.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, I know that, your answer and my answer works fine, ill accept the best answer on the time threshold is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did (tested and worked successfully):

the form page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    localStorage.clear();

    ...

    $('form').on('submit', function(){

        $('#added-items-list').val(JSON.stringify(localStorage["added_items"]));
    });
});
```

the items page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var added_items = [];

    if(localStorage.getItem("added_items")===null){

        localStorage["added_items"] = JSON.stringify(added_items);
    }
    else {

        // Parse the serialized data back into an array of objects
        added_items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('added_items'));
    }

    $('.items-list .one-item').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(added_items.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) < 0){

            added_items.push($(this).attr('href'));
            localStorage.setItem('added_items', JSON.stringify(added_items));
        }
    else{

        alert("item already exist");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Three possible reasons

1.) `form` reloads page

2). `if(added_items.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) < 0)` returns `false`

3). Single `.one-item` element having `$(this).attr("href")`, see 2)

---

Utiltizing `localStorage` ; note, untested

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var added_items = localStorage.getItem("items") || [] ;

  $('.items-list .one-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (typeof added_items === "string") {
      added_items = JSON.parse(added_items);
    }
    if (added_items.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) < 0) {
      added_items.push($(this).attr('href'));
      localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(added_items));
      // note, not certain if page reloads here ?
      // should $('#added-items-list').val(localStorage.getItem("items"));
      // be called before `ajaxLoad` ?
      ajaxLoad('<?=Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('
        bookings / item '); ?>', $('.added-items'), {
          item: $(this).attr('href')
        }, true);          
      $('#added-items-list').val(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    } else {

      alert("item already exist");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Its difficult to include the html, because I am getting it by multiple ajax calls, so it will a large and complex code to share, but I think there is something reloads the page. thanks.

Comment: @Mohammad Could try using `localStorage` to save array in string format which should be accessible after page reload using  `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, tried `localStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage ?

Comment: please give me a full method to be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var added_items = [];
    ...
}
```

seems located inside ajax loaded content so this code run every ajax call.
Your should move at least `var added_items = [];` outside of ajax reloaded content.